# using break in ternary/operator expression giving "Expected Output"

Tags: javascript, typescript, conditional-operator

I created a function for getting last child element using TypeScript.

If I use normal `if/else` typescript not raising any error.

```js
function lastChildElement(element: HTMLElement) {
  let lastChild = element.lastChild

  while (lastChild && lastChild.nodeType != 1) {
    if (lastChild.previousSibling) {
      lastChild = lastChild.previousSibling
    } else {
      break
    }
  }

  return lastChild
}
```

but when using ternary/conditional expression

```js
function lastChildElement(element: HTMLElement) {
  let lastChild = element.lastChild

  while (lastChild && lastChild.nodeType != 1) {
    lastChild.previousSibling ? lastChild = lastChild.previousSibling : break
  }

  return lastChild
}
```

typescript underlining `break` keyword and raising `Expression expected.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conditional operator *evaluates to a value*. That is, if you have

```
someExpression ? someOtherExpression : yetAnotherExpression
```

The entire thing will then evaluate to either `someOtherExpression` or `yetAnotherExpression`.

But `break` is not a value - it's not an expression - it's a statement that can't be evaluated as anything, so it's not permitted in the context where an expression is expected.

For similar reasons, you can't do:

```
while (someCondition) {
  const something = break;
  // ...
```

which just doesn't make sense.

Use `if`/`else`, so that you can `break` as a standalone statement if needed.

That said, a better alternative to iterating through all children is to select the last *element* child directly.

```
const lastChildElement = (element: HTMLElement) => element.lastElementChild;
```

No loops needed.